# Jquery Add class when element is in view

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code which checks if the class is in view and if it is it adds a class, but for some apperent reason it does work. I'm trying to add the class box-active only if the divs in view.

i've been at it for over an hour, can you guys tell me what's wrong with the code?

codepen:
http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/rLRZrJ

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#next').click(function(){
    if ($('.in1').next('.t1').length) {

       $('.t1').animate({left:'-1000px'})
        $('.in1').removeClass('in1')
                    .next('.t1')
                    .addClass('in1');
    }
      });
      $('#next').click(function(){
    if ($('.in2').next('.t2').length) {
           $('.t2').animate({right:'-1000px'})
        $('.in2').removeClass('in2')
                    .next('.t2')
                    .addClass('in2');
        }
          });
          $('#next').click(function(){
    if ($('.in3').next('.t3').length) {
       $('.t3').animate({bottom:'-1000px'})
        $('.in3').removeClass('in3')
                    .next('.t3')
                    .addClass('in3');
      }
  });

  $('#prev').click(function(){
    if ($('.in1').prev('.t1').length) {

        $('.t1').animate({left:'-1000px'})
        $('.in1').removeClass('in1')
                    .prev('.t1')
                    .addClass('in1');

     }
  });
    $('#prev').click(function(){
    if ($('.in2').prev('.t2').length) {
        $('.t2').animate({right:'-1000px'})           
        $('.in2').removeClass('in2')
                    .prev('.t2')
                    .addClass('in2');
    }
  });
    $('#prev').click(function(){
    if ($('.in3').prev('.t3').length) {
        $('.t3').animate({bottom:'-1000px'})           
        $('.in3').removeClass('in3')
                    .prev('.t3')
                    .addClass('in3');

    }
  });

    var $animation_elements = $('.box');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
      (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('box-active');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('box-active');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');

});
```

css

```
html,body,section{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#next,#prev{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:101;
}

#next{
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
}

#prev{
  left:0px;
}



.t1{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:43%;
  background-color: #c92639;
      position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
}

.t2{
    background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: -1000px;
}


.t3{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -1000px;
   background-color: #c8c8c8;

}

.out{
    -webkit-animation:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-name: out3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation:forwards;
    animation-name: out3;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes out3 {
      from {bottom: 0px;}
      to {bottom: -1000px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes t1 {
  from {left: -1000px;}
      to {left: 0px;}
}

.t2,.t3{
height: 50%;
    width: 57%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.in1{
    -webkit-animation:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-name: t1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation:forwards;
    animation-name: t1;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes t1 {
      from {left: -1000px;}
      to {left: 0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes t1 {
  from {left: -1000px;}
      to {left: 0px;}
}
.in2{
  -webkit-animation:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-name: t2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation:forwards;
    animation-name: t2;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes t2 {
      from {top: -1000px;}
      to {top: 0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes t2 {
      from {top: -1000px;}
      to {top: 0px;}
}
.in3{
    -webkit-animation:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-name: t3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation:forwards;
    animation-name: t3;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes t3 {
      from {bottom: -1000px;}
      to {bottom: 0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes t3 {
      from {bottom: -1000px;}
      to {bottom: 0px;}
}

#logo >h1{
    color: white;
}

#logo >h3{
        width: 58%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}


.t2 >img{
    margin-top: 11%;
}

#logo{
    margin-top: 40%;
}

.t3>ul{
    display: inline-table;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.t3>ul>li{
    display: inline-table;
    width: 33%;

}

.t3>ul>li>div>img{
    width: 53%;
    margin-top: 25%;
}

#home{
    display: none !important;
}

#circle1,#circle2,#circle3{
    border-radius: 128px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

#circle1{
    background: #32325f;
}

#circle2{
    background: white;
}

#circle3{
    background: #ef9d34;
}


#case{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:99;
}

.stern1{
  background:blue;
}
.box {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 200px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 200px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 200, 0px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.box-active {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

html

```
<section id="cases">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="next">
  <h1>next</h1>
</div>
<div id="prev">
  <h1>prev</h1>
</div>

<!--page1-->
  <div id="tcee1" class="t1 in1">
     <div id="logo"><img src="img/cee.png" id="cee">
            <div id="underline"></div>
            <br>
            <h1>BRINGING AN OFFLINE ENCOUNTER TO AN ONLINE RELATION</h1><br>
            <h3>Every day Cee-Platform helps their customers to build a bridge between their offline and online marketing challenges.</h3>
        </div>
   </div>
    <div id="tstern1" class="t1" style="background:blue;">
    </div>
    <div id="tsky1" class="t1" style="background:black;">   
    </div>

    <div id="tcee2" class="t2 in2">
      <img src="img/ceedev.png">
    </div>
    <div id="tstern2" class="t2">
    </div>
    <div id="tsky2" class="t2">
    </div>

    <div id="tcee3" class="t3 in3">
       <ul>
            <li class="box">
                <div id="circle1">
                <img src="img/computer.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>Responsiv</h2><br>
                <p>My expierences with developing websites has learned me to make them structualy responsive from the ground up making it accesible for all platforms</p>
            </li>
            <li class="box">
                <div  id="circle2">
                <img src="img/g.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>SEO</h2><br>
                <p>Optimizing your website to result with high results on googles googles list</p>            
            </li>
            <li class="box">
                <div id="circle3">
                <img src="img/hand.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>Storytelling</h2><br>
                <p>With every website you want to tell a story, it doens't matter if you want to tell your visitor how aswesome your compeny or how important your goal is. I'll make it the best one out there</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!--page2-->
    <div id="tstern3" class="t3">
        <ul>
            <li class="box">
                <div id="circle1">

                </div>

            </li>
            <li class="box">
                <div id="circle2">

                </div>

            </li >
            <li class="box">
                <div id="circle3">

                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!--page3-->
    <div id="tcee3" class="t3">
        <ul>
            <li class="box">
                <div id="circle1">
                </div>

            </li>
            <li class="box">
                <div id="circle2">

                </div>           
            </li>
            <li class="box">
                <div id="circle3">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 element_top_position: 1050
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 window_bottom_position: 0
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 element_bottom_position: 1200
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 window_top_position: 0
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 element_top_position: 1050
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 window_bottom_position: 0
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 element_bottom_position: 1200
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 window_top_position: 0
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 element_top_position: 1050
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 window_bottom_position: 0
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 element_bottom_position: 1200
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 window_top_position: 0
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 element_top_position: 1050
console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 window_bottom_position: 0

 if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
      (element_top_position >= window_bottom_position)) {


element_top_position >= window_bottom_position
```

if you make it true then it will only execute as by logging window or the above test cases output. position it is usually zero thats why active class is not being added.

Comment: but eventualy the position goed to 0 why doesn't it added it then?